# Gate bias voltage in class C amplifier

Tags: mosfet, amplifier, efficiency, bias

**Question**

How should the gate of the MOSFET be biased to achieve maximum efficiency (in class c amplifier), when gain is not important?

**Explanation**

- On the one hand, in the tutorial ([link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gYbMpu4NoZo)) it is shown that in order to increase the efficiency of the circuit, the bias voltage should be lowered (below 0V), and the input signal voltage should be increased so that the circuit has a very small conduction angle.
- But on the other hand, in the reference circuit of the MRF101AN transistor ([link](https://www.nxp.com/products/radio-frequency/rf-industrial-scientific-and-medical/1-600-mhz-broadcast-and-ism/mrf101an-reference-circuits:MRF101AN-REFCirc), pdf can be downloaded at the bottom of the page in design resources tab), the author gives a completely different strategy:

> Raise the gate voltage slowly until the drain current reaches the desired level (drain quiescent current IDQ = 100 mA typically). The gate voltage should typically be around 2.5 V.

And he achieved about 80% efficiency.

- Why such diametrically different approaches? What are the advantages of both solutions?
- Are there any other worthwhile transistor biasing strategies worth considering for achieving maximum efficiency?